# OpenCV how to use UsacParams and specify USAC method

Tags: opencv

I am using openCV 4.5 and I'm using USAC to find the fundamental matrix. This works fine for specifying a USAC method:

```
import cv2
a,b = cv2.FindFundamentalMat(pts1, pts2, cv2.USAC_FAST)
```

and this works fine for specifying USAC parameters:

```
params = cv2.UsacParams()
params.maxIterations=700
a,b = cv2.FindFundamentalMat(pts1, pts2, params)
```

But I can't figure out how to specify both the method and the settings. Or does the method determine the settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the C++ source code, we can see that the two different ways of calling the function (with or without the UsacParams) lead to different calls to setParameters.

In conclusion, you're right that **the choice of method (e.g. USAC_FAST) determines the settings** (at least in C++ code).

From https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/calib3d/src/usac/ransac_solvers.cpp

If you pass UsacParams:

```
void setParameters (Ptr<Model> &params, EstimationMethod estimator, const UsacParams &usac_params, bool mask_needed) {
    params = Model::create(usac_params.threshold, estimator, usac_params.sampler, usac_params.confidence, usac_params.maxIterations, usac_params.score);
    params->setLocalOptimization(usac_params.loMethod);
    params->setLOSampleSize(usac_params.loSampleSize);
    params->setLOIterations(usac_params.loIterations);
    params->setParallel(usac_params.isParallel);
    params->setNeighborsType(usac_params.neighborsSearch);
    params->setRandomGeneratorState(usac_params.randomGeneratorState);
    params->maskRequired(mask_needed);
}
```

If you pass a method instead of UsacParams:

```
void setParameters (int flag, Ptr<Model> &params, EstimationMethod estimator, double thr,
        int max_iters, double conf, bool mask_needed) {
    switch (flag) {
        case USAC_DEFAULT:
            params = Model::create(thr, estimator, SamplingMethod::SAMPLING_UNIFORM, conf, max_iters, ScoreMethod::SCORE_METHOD_MSAC);
            params->setLocalOptimization(LocalOptimMethod ::LOCAL_OPTIM_INNER_AND_ITER_LO);
            break;
        case USAC_MAGSAC:
            params = Model::create(thr, estimator, SamplingMethod::SAMPLING_UNIFORM, conf, max_iters, ScoreMethod::SCORE_METHOD_MAGSAC);
            params->setLocalOptimization(LocalOptimMethod ::LOCAL_OPTIM_SIGMA);
            params->setLOSampleSize(params->isHomography() ? 75 : 50);
            params->setLOIterations(params->isHomography() ? 15 : 10);
            break;
        case USAC_PARALLEL:
            params = Model::create(thr, estimator, SamplingMethod::SAMPLING_UNIFORM, conf, max_iters, ScoreMethod::SCORE_METHOD_MSAC);
            params->setParallel(true);
            params->setLocalOptimization(LocalOptimMethod ::LOCAL_OPTIM_INNER_LO);
            break;
        case USAC_ACCURATE:
            params = Model::create(thr, estimator, SamplingMethod::SAMPLING_UNIFORM, conf, max_iters, ScoreMethod::SCORE_METHOD_MSAC);
            params->setLocalOptimization(LocalOptimMethod ::LOCAL_OPTIM_GC);
            params->setLOSampleSize(20);
            params->setLOIterations(25);
            break;
        case USAC_FAST:
            params = Model::create(thr, estimator, SamplingMethod::SAMPLING_UNIFORM, conf, max_iters, ScoreMethod::SCORE_METHOD_MSAC);
            params->setLocalOptimization(LocalOptimMethod ::LOCAL_OPTIM_INNER_AND_ITER_LO);
            params->setLOIterations(5);
            params->setLOIterativeIters(3);
            break;
        case USAC_PROSAC:
            params = Model::create(thr, estimator, SamplingMethod::SAMPLING_PROSAC, conf, max_iters, ScoreMethod::SCORE_METHOD_MSAC);
            params->setLocalOptimization(LocalOptimMethod ::LOCAL_OPTIM_INNER_LO);
            break;
        case USAC_FM_8PTS:
            params = Model::create(thr, EstimationMethod::Fundamental8,SamplingMethod::SAMPLING_UNIFORM, conf, max_iters,ScoreMethod::SCORE_METHOD_MSAC);
            params->setLocalOptimization(LocalOptimMethod ::LOCAL_OPTIM_INNER_LO);
            break;
        default: CV_Error(cv::Error::StsBadFlag, "Incorrect flag for USAC!");
    }
    // do not do too many iterations for PnP
    if (estimator == EstimationMethod::P3P) {
        if (params->getLOInnerMaxIters() > 15)
            params->setLOIterations(15);
        params->setLOIterativeIters(0);
    }

    params->maskRequired(mask_needed);
}
```

For more information, check out the descriptions of the different parameters here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d1/df1/md__build_master-contrib_docs-lin64_opencv_doc_tutorials_calib3d_usac.html